# Invoke method on property of each bean in collection

Tags: java

Suppose I have a class A with property b

```
Class A {
    public int b;
}
```

There is a collection that containes instances of class A
ArrayList col

How can I get an array of all values of property b from col?
Is there a way more elegant than iteration through col and getting property of each object and then passign values of b to array?

```
LIst<Integer> propertyValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (A a : col){
    propertyValues.add(a.b);
}
```

Maybe a [Spring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework) utility method or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're stuck with the above.

Perhaps [Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/index.html) may give you something more acceptable. See the [CollectionUtils](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html) class, and in particular the [collect()](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#collect%28java.util.Collection,%20org.apache.commons.collections.Transformer%29) and [forAllDo()](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#forAllDo%28java.util.Collection,%20org.apache.commons.collections.Closure%29) methods.

Alternatively, [JXPath](http://commons.apache.org/jxpath/) can do this for you (it provides XPath-like navigation over Java beans). You can specify an expression such as `/A/@b` and it will return a collection of `b`. It's a little excessive if you're doing this once, but if you're iterating and navigating over collections it's a very concise way of doing this.

EDIT: As I pointed out in a comment below, Scala will do this in a much more concise form. If you're running on the JVM and doing a lot of collection work like the above, you may want to check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you think this is elegant?  Almost anything shorter would require removing some type information - generally you choose to program in Java because you want to use a strongly- and statically-typed language.

Or maybe because it has tons of libraries and frameworks and lots of Manning books and all your inherited legacy code is in Java.  Whatever.

Comment: Not true. Scala is typed and will do the above a *lot* more concisely. e.g. col.map{ a => a.b }. That's typed and returns a collection of 'b'

Comment: That fragment has no type information - what does the rest of it look like?

Comment: Ah sorry, I meant to say statically typed.  Always mix those up.

Comment: Scala uses type inference. So it derives the type information statically from the earlier usages. The above 'col' will be a (say) List[A], and the Scala compiler then determines what A.b is and statically derives a new list type.

Comment: Note this is *not* dynamic typing.

Comment: Ok, so its typing works the same as ML.  Type inference is nice but it has a lot of pitfalls and can't catch every case (leading to errors like 'expected 'a -> 'a list but received 'a -> 'a list - not sure if this sort of thing happens in Scala also).  It doesn't have quite the same effect - certainly for the reader, if not the compiler - as stating all your assumptions explicitly.

Comment: But you *can* state these explicitly. Scala will let you do that to remove ambiguities.

Answer (score 2):

Use [LambdaJ](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj):

```
List<Integer> bees = collect(originalList, on(A).b);
```

Basically LamdbaJ's idea is to get all the nifty list methods available in functional languages to Java and then it even goes as far as adding [it's own version of closures](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/Closures) to the whole pile. Definately worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the JDK collections framework doesn't have anything more elegant than the iteration solution.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the following solution

```
List propertyList = new ArrayList();
CollectionUtils.collect(list,new Transformer() {          
    @Override
    public Object transform(Object input) {
        return ((LogMessage)input).getLogRunIds();
    }
    },propertyList);
```

Unfortunately, Transform interface doesn't allow using generics, so i have to use explicit casts

Many thakns to Brian Agnew for an insight